# Encryption and Decryption in C

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, cryptography, hashcode

I have written a program in `C`, which encrypts and decrypts a c-styled string (`const char *`) and print the result to *stdout*. It requires `key (const char *)` and it's hash is calculated using [*Polynomial Rolling Hash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Polynomial_rolling_hash).

My program makes sure that the hash of `key` must be in-between `0...128`, using statement like `size_t hash = get_hash(key) % 128;`. **My code works well if I provide a good `key`, but if the `key` is bad *(plain[i] ± hash < 0)*, then it exits saying `could not encrypt`.**

I have implemented all suggestion I got from my previous questions (not related this one).

Here's my code: [**`TRY GOOD_KEY`**](https://godbolt.org/z/Gc43v496x) | [**`TRY BAD_KEY`**](https://godbolt.org/z/9Gqxa7s6T)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// gets hash of a string using Polynomial Rolling Hash 
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Polynomial_rolling_hash
static size_t get_hash(const char *a)
{
    if (a && *a != 0)
    {
        size_t p = 53;
        size_t m = 1e9 + 9;
        long long power_of_p = 1;
        long long hash_val = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            hash_val = (hash_val + (a[i] - 97 + 1) * power_of_p) % m;
            power_of_p = (power_of_p * p) % m;
        }
        return (hash_val % m + m) % m;
    }
    return (size_t)-1;
}

// encrypts `plain` using `key` and stores the output on heap allocated memory `out`
static bool encrypt(const char *plain, char **out, const char *key)
{
    if (!plain || !out || !key)
        return false;
    size_t hash = get_hash(key) % 128;
    size_t len = strlen(plain);
    bool add = true;

    *out = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (!(*out))
        return false;

    for (size_t i = 0; plain[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (add == true && plain[i] + hash > '\0')
        {
            (*out)[i] = plain[i] + hash;
            add = false;
        }
        else if (add == false && plain[i] - hash > '\0')// should not be less than zero
        {
            (*out)[i] = plain[i] - hash;
            add = true;
        }
        else
        {
            free(*out);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// decrypts `enc` using `key` and stores the output on heap allocated memory `out`
static bool decrypt(const char *enc, char **out, const char *key)
{
    if (!enc || !out || !key)
        return false;
    size_t hash = get_hash(key) % 128;
    size_t len = strlen(enc);

    bool add_inrv = true;

    *out = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (!(*out))
        return false;

    for (size_t i = 0; enc[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (add_inrv == true && enc[i] - hash > '\0')
        {
            (*out)[i] = enc[i] - hash;
            add_inrv = false;
        }
        else if (add_inrv == false && enc[i] + hash > '\0')
        {
            (*out)[i] = enc[i] + hash;
            add_inrv = true;
        }
        else
        {
            free(*out);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        perror("not enough input\nUsage: <MESSAGE> <KEY>");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Your text: `%s`\n", argv[1]);
    char *enc, *after_dnc;

    if(!encrypt(argv[1], &enc, argv[2])){
        perror("could not encrypt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Encrypted: `%s`\n", enc);

    if(!decrypt(enc, &after_dnc, argv[2])){
        perror("could not decrypt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Decrypted: `%s`\n", after_dnc);

    free(enc);
    free(after_dnc);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*For output please use online compiler given above.*
I'm using `GCC v11.2.0` on `Arch Linux x86_64` using `C17` standard.

Comment: Please define a C standard. What sign do you expect `char`s to have, or `-42 % 128`? Are you comfortable with `0 == hash(key)`? What type do you assume `plain[i] ± hash` to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the following I keep mentioning problems I see, that doesn't mean there isn't good:

- there are comments telling what each function is good for
  (but for `main()`)
  even where most are static (Not to be used outside compilation unit - why?)
- I find the code fairly readable:
  naming and code formatting are inconspicious
  (hm. `_inrv`?)
- you strive for *const correctness*

In all functions but `get_hash()`, you don't nest `if (<can proceed>)`s, but use *early out*. (I'd rather use `'a'` than `97`)

`encrypt()` seems to be to alternately add and subtract `hash`:
use a signed type and keep adding & inverting instead of conditional execution.
`encrypt()` and `decrypt()` are basically the same function - let's give using a common implementation a try:

```
static bool
crypt(const char *message, char ** const pout, const char *const key, bool add);

// encrypts `plain` using `key` and stores the output on heap allocated memory `out`
bool encrypt(const char *plain, char **out, const char *key)
{
    return crypt(plain, out, key, true);
}

// decrypts `enc` using `key` and stores the output on heap allocated memory `out`
bool decrypt(const char *enc, char **out, const char *key)
{
    return crypt(enc, out, key, false);
}

#define MAGIC   (128-1-1)
// crypts `message` using `key` and stores the output on heap allocated memory `pout`
static bool
crypt(const char *message, char ** const pout, const char *const key, bool add)
{
    if (!message || !pout || !key)
        return false;

    size_t len = strlen(message);

    char *out = *pout = malloc(len + 1);
    if (NULL == out)
        return false;
    out[len] = '\0';
    if (0 == len)
        return true;
    long hash = 1 + (get_hash(key) % (long)MAGIC);
    if (!add)
        hash = -hash;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        out[i] = message[i] + hash;
        hash = -hash;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `_inrv` stands for *inverse*

Comment: (`additive_inverse`, `add_inverse` - OK; `add_invr` sort of. Positive about `_inrv`?)

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid *unsigned* math mistakes**

> My code works well if I provide a good key, but if the key is bad (plain[i] ± hash < 0)

`plain[i] ± hash < 0` is **never** true.  This is an *unsigned* compare.  An *unsigned* sum/difference is never less than 0.

`hash` is an *unsigned* type and so dominates the compare.  Note that `enc[i]` may be negative.  Better to force the math, somehow to not depend on wrap-around

```
Really correct??
enc[i] - hash > '\0'
// This is the same as 
enc[i] - hash != '\0'
```

I suspect OP wants something like below.

```
enc[i] + CHAR_MAX + 1 > hash + CHAR_MAX + 1
```

... or force signed compare:

```
plain[i] ± (long) hash < 0
```

I am still unclear what the `enc[i] - hash > 0` is really doing in the comment-less section of code.

**Reduce with a *prime***

`size_t hash = get_hash(key) % 128;` only uses the lower 7 bits of `get_hash(key)`.  If the hash function `get_hash()` is a good one, then that is OK.  Yet using `size_t hash = get_hash(key) % some_prime;` can make a weak hash better.

**Do not compare a `bool` against `true`**

```
// if (add == true ...
if (add ...
```

**Unclear comment/code**

"... sure that the hash of key must be in-between 0...128, using statement like size_t hash = get_hash(key) % 128" is unclear.  Using `get_hash(key) % 128` makes a key of [0...127], not 0...128 - depending on what that means.  Be more explicit on the edge values to avoid off-by-one errors.

**Size by the referenced object, not type**

To know if `sizeof(char)` is correct, it obliges a review of the declaration, wherever it may be.

```
// Avoid
*out = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
```

Instead, size to the object.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// Better
*out = calloc(len + 1, sizeof **out); // or some variation.
```

**Minor: avoid negations**

Rather than

```
if (!(*out))
```

consider

```
if (*out == NULL)
```

Avoidable use of `!` tends to obfuscate.

**Only for the pedantic**

With rare (soon to be obsolete) non-2's complement, `plain[i] != '\0'` is a problem when `char` is *signed* (I wonder if such an animal exist today) as that stops the iteration on -0, when it should not.

A fix for that, and to avoid mixed sign-ness math, is to access strings via `unsigned char*`.

Comment: *I am still unclear what the enc[i] - hash > 0 is really doing in the comment-less section of code.* --- It was making sure that any character of encrypted and decrypted text doesn't contain `'\0'`.